# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined JQUERY autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

This scripts are used,
https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

I am using jQuery Autocomplete for searching users from my DB.

Below is controller which returns Json:

```
public function searchusers1() {
    if ($_GET) {
        $query = $this -> input -> get('query');

        $searcharray = $this -> model_usermanage -> searchuser($query);

        $a_json = array();
        $a_json_row = array();
        foreach($searcharray as $row) {
            //$user_firstname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['user_firstname']));
            //$user_lastname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['user_lastname']));
            $user_email = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['user_email']));
            //$a_json_row["user_firstname"] = $user_firstname;
            $a_json_row["user_email"] = $user_email;

            array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
        }
        echo json_encode($a_json);
    }
}
```

Below is my jQuery:

```
$('#reply_bcc').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/hi/test/searchusers1',
    minChars: 3,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.data + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

Here is my JSON response:

```
[{"user_email":"hi@test.com"},{"user_email":"hello@au.com"},{"user_email":"testing@123.com"},]
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" name="reply_bcc" id="reply_bcc" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**My PROBLEM is:**

I am getting below error in console and I can not see this searched values as dropdown in my html input:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What's going wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are not following the [api guidelines for response](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/#jquery-autocomplete-response-format).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation explains "Response from the server must be JSON formatted following JavaScript object:"

```html
{
    // Query is not required as of version 1.2.5
    "query": "Unit",
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

And you are just returning an array without the format value/data. You can change your format in PHP or use the "transformResult" function to create the suggestions property with your array.

You should add an object in your PHP code:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->suggestions = $a_json;
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: I managed to get it with { "Value": "XX" }, but still have same issue, How can i add { "Suggestions" : [...] } in PHP?

Comment: You need to create an object. Let me update the answer.

Comment: You are super, it worked, but just a correction, stdObject() not working, it should be $obj = new stdClass(); Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call stdClass(). The function json_encode() converts the associative array to JSON for you. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$query="";
if (isset($_GET['query'])) $query=$db_handler->real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$sql="SELECT `user_id`,`user_name` FROM `some_table`
    WHERE `user_name` LIKE '%{$query}%' ORDER BY `user_name`";
$res=$db_handler->query($sql);

if ($res->num_rows > 0)
{
    $data=array();
    while($row = $res->fetch_object())
    {
        $data[]=array("value" => $row->user_name, "data" => $row->user_id);
    }
    $res->free();
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("suggestions" => $data));
?>
```

The above code will output something like this:

```
{"suggestions":[{"value":"Joe Blow","data":"1000"},{"value":"Jane Blow","data":"1001"}]}
```

This is the format .autocomplete expects: JavaScript Object Notation.